# Getting DIV tags to extend to bottom of page or content

Tags: css, html, layout

I have a setup for a left navigation bar on our website that.  The way it is displayed is to have a header image (usually the client's name) at the top of the nav, then to have a table that holds a number of options about what to do.  These options vary depending on what the client is.  When displaying this nav, there are two images that run down the sides of the primary table, used as borders.  These are skinnable images that are one by one pixel images.  This way, each client's skin can be a different color while referencing the same image name in the CSS file.

Before we added doc types to these pages, the images were extending to the bottom of the page or the bottom of the content inside of the table, whichever was longer.  Now, adding doc types to make the page standard, I cannot get it to do the same thing.

My setup is that I have one DIV as the header which simply holds the header image.  Then, I have a DIV as a container with three DIV elements as children.  The first and last ones hold the one pixel image as the left and right border and the middle div holds the content table.

I can't set the border image DIVs to 100% height, because the page size will be 100% + the size of the header image.  And I can't just rely on the image going to the bottom of the content, because it needs to be the entire length of the page if the content doesn't take up the entire page.  I'm at a loss of what to do here, short of using javascript to calculate what the size of the DIVs should be when I resize the page.

By the way, I'm trying to shoot for all browsers, so both IE (at least 9) and Chrome are m test cases.  Linking code here to show what my problem is.  As you can see, the left, content, and right divs extend past the bottom of the page, which I do not want to happen.

```
//HTML

<html>
    <body>
        <div class="NavHeader">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="NavBody">
            <div id="NavLeft"> &nbsp;</div>
            <div id="NavContent">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="NavRight">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

// CSS

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.NavHeader {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
#NavBody {
    height: 100%;
}
#NavLeft {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1px;
}
#NavContent {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
#NavRight {
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Can you supply a link or screenshot?

Comment: Could people please leave a comment explaining why this question is not valid and why they are down-voting it, rather then simply down voting the question with no reasoning?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into a similar case in the past and all I was able to come up with was using javascript...

CSS (as far as I know) doesn't really have that dynamic capability that you are looking for.